# Java perl file delete/delete files older than n number of days

Tags: java, perl, delete-file

I am using Java 6.

I am writing a method where I have to delete files older than n number of days.
This will be house keeping job, running as per schedule.

What is the best way to do this?

1. Write the method in Java to check and delete the files. But I think using Java we can get the file creation time.
2. Write in perl and call the script from Java.

Any other suggestions are also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this just from java. No need to use perl.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class DeleteOlderThan
{

    private static long daysAgo;

    private static void delete(File f) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            for (File l : f.listFiles())
                delete(l);
        }
        if (f.lastModified() <= daysAgo) {
            f.delete();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1 * new Integer(args[1]));
        daysAgo = cal.getTimeInMillis();

        delete(new File(args[0]));
    }
}
```

Running `java DeleteOlderThan /my/path days` will delete files recursively in the path older than days.

Answer (score 1):

I would not call perl from Java.  There's no point to it.

If you're running a *nix box, just cron a bash command to do it.

If you're using Windows, then do it in Java. Examples of such things are all over the web.

Comment: so you mean it is possible from java without using any additional library?

Comment: @adi I believe so.  Check out the File class.  Browse for samples.  It's all pretty common stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Check-out Apache Commons-IO, FileUtils, particularly the isFileOlder(File file, Date date) method.  Here's a link to the JavaDoc:

http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

Lots of great utility methods for handling files in that class.